# Display data from controller to view

Tags: html, laravel

I want to display some data from the following controller

```
if($this->verifyTKey($request['token'])['message'] === 'not'){
        abort(404);
    }else{

            return view('pay')->with('datas',$this->verifyTKey($request->header('token')));
    }
}
```

to view

```
<p id="amount"></p>
```

Comment: So what is the issue you face?

Comment: When i put the following codes in my view: {@foreach($datas as $data)
                                <h2>{{$data->amount}}}</h2>
@endforeach} it show me the Undefined variable error

Comment: @Dacy Can you please print only **datas** object.

Comment: @Dacy you should include the error you have in your question when you ask, and also if applicable an expected result.

Comment: Is the result of `$this->verifyTKey()` a collection? Are you sure its not null, empty? Are you sure the `amount` property is in each item in the _collection_? these are pointers I'd suggest you check.